# grails hasOne but does not belong to

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm

I'm working on a project and have an `Invoice` domain class that currently `hasOne=[billingAddress:Address]`  When I try to launch my server, I get the following error:

```
hasOne property [Invoice.billingAddress] is not bidirectional. Specify the other side of the relationship!
```

I don't want to assign the other side of the relationship though... Invoices have a billing address but Addresses do not belong to Invoices.  Addresses belong to Users!!!

What is the proper way to handle this situation?

Comment: Just use `Address billingAddress` instead?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like you just need a normal association rather than a `hasOne`:

```
class Invoice {
  // other properties

  Address billingAddress
}
```

The `hasOne` mechanism is a way to change the database representation for an association, with a conventional `Address billingAddress` you'll end up with a `billing_address_id` column in the `invoice` table, whereas with `hasOne` the association is instead represented by a foreign key in the `address` table - this representation only allows one `Invoice` for each `Address`, which is why the association has to be bidirectional.